# Selenium IDE storeEval for xpath threw an exception: missing ) after argument list

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

Here's the code snippet:

```
<tr>  
    <td>storeEval</td>  
    <td>substring-after(id('dateTimeRecurring')//ul[contains(@class,'table-data-row')][1]/@id, 't')</td>  
    <td>rec</td>  
</tr>
```

Log:

```
[info] Executing: |storeEval | substring-after(id('dateTimeRecurring')//ul[contains(@class,'table-data-row')][1]/@id, 't') | rec |  
[info] script is: substring-after(id('dateTimeRecurring')//ul[contains(@class,'table-data-row')][1]/@id, 't')  
**[error] Threw an exception: missing ) after argument list**
```

The xpath expression returns the right result, when I run it outside Selenium IDE. The result is a number "4831435861826033152".

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  Why do you want to store this, and what are you really trying to store?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Would love to see the snippet of html you're trying to capture. I have a feeling what you want to do is actually MUCH simplier than the way you're trying.

Maybe store the text value and then do your javascript parsing on that variable?

Answer (score 1):

The `storeEval` command takes a JavaScript expression not an XPath locator.

Comment: Thanks Ross. Do you know if Selenium IDE allows storing the value of a XPath expression? The value is dynamic, which is the reason why I had to use xpath to store the value and use it in a different part of the script. Not familiar with how to do the same in JavaScript.

Comment: Since `storeEval` takes a JavaScript expression, I tried the JavaScript route of evaluating an XPath expression and storing the value. Currently stuck at this point, as I am not very familiar with JS.

Comment: `var rec=document.evaluate("substring-after(id('dateTimeRecurring')//ul[contains(@class,'table-data-row')][1]/@id, 't')", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
var thisrec = rec.iterateNext();
alert("Found: " + rec.ANY_TYPE);`

Comment: if you wont to store a value in the xpath position it is better to use  command "storeValue".

Answer (score 0):

storeEval
    substring-after(id('dateTimeRecurring')//ul[contains(@class,'table-data-row')][1]/@id, 't')
    rec

Here substring-after... Function should be the part of Javascript.